# Uncertain behaviour of subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess, snmp

```
snmpset -v 2c -c private <oid> integer 6
try:
    x = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
except Exception:
    msg = "Some error here"
    exit()
```

I have written a python script of which the above code is a part. Sometimes it is executed properly while sometimes it gives the following error:

```
Error in packet.
Reason: noCreation (That table does not support row creation or that object can not ever be created)
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::<oid>
```

I am not able to understand why it is behaving in an uncertain manner. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: This problem seems to be with snmpset and not really Python (as the errors are not from Python).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid so do have any solution for that?

Comment: Please try to run the snmpset process outside of python and check if you can reproduce the error there, then post the data of that call if it fails.

Comment: when I was getting this error, I tried snmpset directly from the server. It is producing the same result. For some 3-4 times, it is executing but following then, I am getting the same error as above.

Comment: This error message comes from the server. This is not an error in your script. You need to contact the vendor of the equipment you are interacting with, for technical support.